# How to hide the title if title value of link field is empty in drupal 7 views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am using drupal 7. I want to create a list for content type promo. I have two fields in that one.

1. Title
2. Link(Created using the link module of drupal 7. So having two fields under this 1.Title. 2.URL).

My requirement is, I have to display the title as a link if title is there otherwise nothing should be displayed. But currently the url is displaying as a link if title is not there.

How can I fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

- Add your link field with formmater: Title, as plain text;
- In 'NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR' check "Hide if empty" and "Hide rewriting if empty";
- In 'REWRITE RESULTS' check "Rewrite the output of this field" --> check "Output this field as a link" and set respective url value token in "Link Path".

In this way you'll get conditioned output.